# Why can't a static variable defined in one cpp file be found in another in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a `variables.cpp`, in which it defines:

```
static MyNamespace::MyClass myObj('input');
```

I have a `variables.h` that is included by `variables.cpp`

And I have a `main.cpp` that includes `variables.h`, which it refers to myObj:

```
MyNameSpace::myObj.doRun();
```

And the compiler complains that: `no member named 'myObj' in namespace 'MyNameSpace'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `MyNameSpace::myObj` declared in the header file?

Comment: You did realize `'input'` is a character literal, not a string literal. I assume this is not done on purpose.

Comment: @NathanOliver no, i see the problem. How do I define `myObj` in variables.cpp after it's been declared in variables.h?

Comment: "I have a `variables.h` that includes `variables.cpp`" Seems like a bad idea. You don't want to be `#include`ing source files, that's practically going to guarantee one-definition rule violations.

Comment: what you think `static` does here?

Comment: @NathanPierson sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Marking a namespace scope object `static` limits its visibility to the file in which it is defined. Get rid of that `static`.

Answer (score 2):

The very purpose of `static` variables is to be file scope, not visible in other files. So naturally they are not then visible, using `static` specifically requests that.

As a consequence, several .cpp files can have a static variable with same name, and they will be different variables. Also as a consequence, if you define a static variable in .h file, then every .cpp file which includes it will have a different variable.

Extra notes:

- In C++ you can achieve similar effect (file scope) by putting the variables in anonymous namespace in the .cpp file.
- `static` class member variables are a different case, they are visible everywhere (in other words, the variable symbol name is exported), and basically behave like non-static global variables which aren't member variables. Yes, it can be a bit confusing, `static` has several different meanings in C++.
- `static` variable can be accessed from other .cpp files, if you create a function which returns a reference (or a pointer) to it in the .cpp file where it is defined. It's lifetime is same as program execution, so this is safe from that point of view. However, thread safety and re-entrancy are then issues which need attention, so you shouldn't do this unless you know *why* you are doing this.

Comment: I  think you mean anonymous namespace, not static namespace

Comment: Is there a deeper common meaning to the word between both usages of `static`? I think they are very old (in terms of C++ revisions), so not defining new keywords was not such a great issue then?

Comment: @Sebastian Not sure of the etymology, but I think `static` originally refers to storage duration. Then C just opted to use it _also_ to mean file scope.

Comment: ...or more precisely, C opted to use `static` global symbol to not be exported. You can have `static` local variables too, which naturally are not exported, because they are local variables, so maybe that's why it felt logical to take this meaning also for global static variables.

Comment: I don't think this solves OP's problems. Clearly, there is no visible declaration at the point of use.

Answer (score 0):

as another answer point out, `static` variable is meant to not shared with others.

---

If you do want to share `myObj`, you should remove the `static` specifier

```cpp
// variables.cpp
MyNamespace::MyClass myObj('input'); // no static
```

and declare it in header file

```cpp
// variables.h
extern MyNamespace::MyClass myObj;
```

---

or, with c++17, another option is use `inline` variable.

```cpp
// variables.h
inline MyNamespace::MyClass myObj('input');

// variables.cpp
// do not redeclare it
```

---

btw, `'input'` is multicharacter literal, most likely not what you want.